# Is there an idiomatic equivalent of "I really loved what you said"?

Tags: idioms

In Armenian, we have an expression which literally can be translated as "You talked|told|said from my heart", and means "I really loved what you said", "I really excited about what you said, since I thought the same" and expresses an emotional solidarity. In English, what is the idiomatic equivalent for it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

WARNING: This answer is for mature audiences. Reader discretion is advised.

I think JBanana comes closest to the intent of your idiom, at least as you express it in English. (I would add "right," however, as in "You took the words *right* out of my mouth.")

To get closer to the poetry of the original would require, well, poetry; and in post-ironic America, at least, flowery or sentimental language is likely to produce unintended consequences, not the least of which is that someone in the group would feel obliged to make a joke about it.

I would probably say something like, "I couldn't agree more." That is much less poetic, but sums up the feeling.

That said, there are some slangy expressions that might hit at the heart of what you are trying to get across, though in different ways.

Young people in the last dozen or so years who are influenced by hip-hop culture might simply say, "Word!"

Older people (in informal situations and among friends) might say "Fuckin' A!" or "Fuckin' A right!" to expression strong agreement and emotional solidarity.

Comment: True dat, Robusto!

Comment: Amen, brother!  Testify!

Answer (score 11):

How about "You took the words out of my mouth"?

Answer (score 7):

You might say "I couldn't have said it better."

Answer (score 4):

To add a couple common ones:

> Hear, hear!
>
> Amen!

Answer (score 3):

"You spoke beautifully" is pretty common.  It can refer to both eloquence and ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Some others:

"Totally!"

"Absolutely!"

Comment: Don't forget "All-encompassingly!" (Mitch Hedberg)

Answer (score 2):

A good idiomatic expression here would be that/it/whatever "spoke to me".

Answer (score 1):

"What s/he said" is another common usage in this category.

Comment: "^This." (if you're writing; not usually said aloud).

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic expressions include, "You really hit the spot," or "You really hit the nail on the head." Or "You hit a home run." (The last from baseball.)

Answer (score 1):

A religious variation may be "from your lips to God's ears" - generally said when one wholeheartedly agrees and hopes that what the other has said will come/prove true.

Answer (score 0):

Would "You spoke my mind" be the equivalent of it?

Comment: Hmmm... I think it is more similar to "You read my mind" (we say that)...

Answer (score 0):

I tend to exclaim "BRAINTWIN!" at moments like these.

Answer (score 0):

If someone said something that particularly moved me, or that I could relate to on a deep level, I would tend to say that their notions or words:

> "struck a chord in/with me."

Answer (score 0):

In the context of someone else speaking from your heart from the idea of "being lionhearted",  comes the saying **"Well roared, lion!"**

Although I admit this is mostly used by descendants of Germanic speakers (from "Gut gebruellt, Loewe!").

**"Well roared, lion!"** is said in a passion of deep approval and feeling of being on the same wave length as the speaker.